# What is the correct expression to use in order to format a date from "yyyyMMdd" to "M/d/yyyy" in SQL Server Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, formatting

I get dates in my dataset in the form "yyyyMMdd" (ie 20080228 means Feb 28, 2008)

I need to convert these to "M/d/yyyy"

Examples:

```
20080228 = 2/28/2008
20080101 = 1/1/2008
20081001 = 10/1/2008
20081212 = 12/12/2008
```

what is the correct expression to handle this?

**EDIT**

The expression that I used (ORDDTE is in the "yyyyMMdd" format and I have a switch for spanish or english date format):

```
=CDate(Mid(First(Fields!ORDDTE.Value, "ReturnTagHeader").ToString(), 5, 2) + "/" + Right(First(Fields!ORDDTE.Value, "ReturnTagHeader").ToString(), 2) + "/" + Left(First(Fields!ORDDTE.Value, "ReturnTagHeader").ToString(), 4)).ToString(IIf(Parameters!Language.Value = "ES", "d/M/yyyy", "M/d/yyyy"))
```

Comment: Added ssrs-expression tag as I feel that it is relevant. If I cannot add tags to the site then why is there a "Taxonomist" badge (Created a tag used by 50 questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot.  You can use the string functions.  I'm guessing that this input/field/param is always going to have a 2 digit month and 2 digit day, so you can get away with this...  Set the expression on the date field as such:

```
=MID(Fields!ORDDTE.Value.ToString(), 5, 2) 
  + "/" + RIGHT(Fields!ORDDTE.Value.ToString(), 2)
  + "/" + LEFT(Fields!ORDDTE.Value.ToString(), 4)
```

You could also try to do something like this... found [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2237)...

```
=System.DateTime.ParseExact(Fields!ORDDTE.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy",System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: I would suggest that the formatdatetime() would be much more concise, but if for some reason that is not available, parsing out the string like shown above may be the only other logical way.

Comment: yep... just giving him another hackerish option.  The only challenge I can see on the formatdatetime is making the ccYYMMdd format readable and convertable.

Comment: formatdatetime is vbscript, RS uses vb dotty netty!
thought you could specify a custom format tho....

Answer (score 2):

If you set an expression on the field you should be able to wrap it in a FormatDateTime()

Example:
`formatdatetime(FieldWhatever, 0)`

The 0 should be the specifier for the particular format you are looking for.

Comment: I should just note that most of my experience is from SSRS 2005. So if for some reason this has been nerfed in 2008 I apologize.

Comment: WTF is the list of valid values for the second argument (0 in your example). RAGE.

Comment: AHAH, [MSDN documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a912f2a0(v=vs.80).aspx) just 5 eligible constants for that argument. [Thavash's SQL Blog](http://thavash.wordpress.com/2007/04/10/working-with-dates-in-reporting-services/) has clear examples for a US locale.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Format(FieldWhatever,"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: The Format function will return a custom formatted date string. The FormatDateTime() function will only return names datetime formats.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you cast the field to a datetime in your sql call in the dataset.

```
Select CAST(DateField AS datetime) As Date FROM DateTable
```

Then for your expression:

```
=Cdate(Fields!Date.Value).ToShortDateString
```

Comment: yeah, converting the date on the sql side is a lot faster than converting it on the report side.

Answer (score 1):

This is making the inference that datevalue is coming to you as an integer which will need to be converted in order to use MID().

DATEVALUE = 20080901 <- yyyyMMdd

= Mid(cSTR(DATEVALUE) ,5 ,2) &"/"&  Mid(cSTR(DATEVALUE) ,7 ,2) &"/"& Mid(cSTR(DATEVALUE) ,1 ,4)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Report Services expressions, you can also format the date from the stored procedure:

```
select 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [dateField], 101) as 'date' 
from someTable
```

This has drawbacks in that this will be universal and if your report has to be internationalized, you will be at a disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer...

Why not set the "Report language" to "User!Language" as [mentioned here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156493.aspx)?
This detects browser settings.

Then "d" for short date. Use CDate if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,30)DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE()),1,4) + 
SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,30)DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE()),6,2) +
SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,30)DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE()),9,2)
```